# How can I read this string in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string such as this: "xxxxxxx , yyyyyyy - zzzzzz"
and sometimes it happens to be "xxxxxxx - zzzzzz"
the length of x may vary.
What I want to get, is always the x word.
Is there an easy way to do this?

What I thought was:
Iterate through the string, append to a stringbuilder every char I read until I read a ",", then break the iteration and I get the word, but this looks pretty messy.

So maybe there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: why didnt you use `string[0]`

Comment: You can use `String.charAt(0)`.

Comment: How about `charAt(0)`?

Comment: Yes, there are several easy ways of doing this.

Comment: I'm sorry, really sorry. But x is not a single character. I know it's my fault, that's why I'm editing the original post. But thanks a lot for your solution, I hope you can find one to my "real" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several ways to get the first character:

```
String str = "x , y - zzzzzz";
System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
System.out.println(str.substring(0, 1));
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^(.).*", "$1"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/2TeGLk)

Choose the one you like more :)

**UPDATE**:

To find the first word, you may use the following regex pattern:

```
String pattern = "[\\s\\p{P}]+";
```

`\s` stands for whitespace, and `\p{P}` stands for punctuation.

You can use `split` with this as in

```
String str = "xxxxxxx , yyyyyyy - zzzzzz";
System.out.println(str.split(pattern)[0]);
str = "xxxxxxx - zzzzzz";
System.out.println(str.split(pattern)[0]);
str = "xxxxxxx, zzzzzz";
System.out.println(str.split(pattern)[0]);
str = "xxxxxxx-zzzzzz";
System.out.println(str.split(pattern)[0]);
```

All will output `xxxxxxx`. However, if you need to restrict the punctuation to some smaller subset, either exclude them in the `&&[^-]` negated subtraction:

```
[\\s\\p{P}&&[^-]]+
```

Or just define your own range:

```
[\\s.,;:]+
```

Just [another demo](https://ideone.com/pPe6TP)

Comment: I guess now I will hear "yes, but..." :)

Comment: I'm sorry, really sorry.
But x is not a single character. I know it's my fault, that's why I'm editing the original post.
But thanks a lot for your solution, I hope you can find one to my "real" question

Comment: Please check my update. I hope it is helpful enough to solve the problem you have.

Comment: Thank you alot and excuse me for the poor writing of my question before.